# Java - Using the "/" as a first parameter throws a java.nio.file.InvalidPathException

Tags: java, path

I'm trying to get a path using the "/" as the First String parameter and "test.txt" as a second String parameter. The desired output is : "/test.txt"

```
Path pth = Paths.get("/", "test.txt");
System.out.println(pth);
```

after running the program i'm getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path 
is missing sharename: /\test.txt
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
at be.bt.test.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

I'm new to java and i need to understand why the JVM is throwing this Exception?

Best regards..

Comment: ```UNC path is missing sharename```

Comment: This appears to be a Unix style path, yet you are on Windows which has a different path syntax that typically includes a drive letter or UNC name. Why do you need to resolve this particular path that isn't applicable to the machine/runtime you're on?

Comment: I got this code as an exercise, after implementing it i got the exception..i just copy and past it in order to run it..but when i change it to                                          
    Path iP = Paths.get("/foo", "First.txt"); it works without UNC or drive letter..Why?